# Do we find advertisements 'in magazines and the media' or 'on magazines and the media'?

Tags: prepositions

> We find advertisements **on** magazines and the media.
>   We find advertisements **in** magazines and the media.

Which preposition is suitable, in or on?

Comment: For both your two referents, ***in*** is far more likely. Note that if they required *different* prepositions you couldn't "delete" the second one as in your example. So it would be *We find them **in** magazines and **on** [the] TV,* for example.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say "advertisements **on** magazines".  [Ngrams search doesn't even list it as ever occurring.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=advertisements+*+magazines&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cadvertisements%20%2A%20magazines%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Badvertisements%20in%20magazines%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badvertisements%20from%20magazines%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badvertisements%20and%20magazines%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badvertisements%20for%20magazines%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Badvertisements%20of%20magazines%3B%2Cc0)  Did you see it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Books and magazines generally have to opened to be used (read), so the content on the pages is considered to be *in* or *inside.*

Saying something is *on* a book or magazine makes it sound like you mean something physically on top of the entire book or magazine.

You can say something is *on* a postcard or 1-page flyer, though, to mean part of the content of the card or flyer.